# How to change the way data in an array is presented in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I found this bit of very useful code on this site:-

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmpArr As Variant
    Dim Dict As Object, tmpDict As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v, key
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Output")

    ' Update to your sheet here
    With ws
        ' You may need to modify this depending on where you range is stored
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2))

        tmpArr = rng.Value

        For i = LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1)
            ' Test if value exists in dictionary. If not add and set up the dictionary item
            If Not Dict.exists(tmpArr(i, 1)) Then
                Set tmpDict = Nothing
                Set tmpDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                Dict.Add key:=tmpArr(i, 1), Item:=tmpDict
            End If
            ' Set nested dictionary to variable so we can edit it
            Set tmpDict = Nothing
            Set tmpDict = Dict(tmpArr(i, 1))

            ' Test if value exists in nested Dictionary, add if not and initiate counter
            If Not tmpDict.exists(tmpArr(i, 2)) Then
                tmpDict.Add key:=tmpArr(i, 2), Item:=1
            Else
                ' Increment counter if it already exists
                tmpDict(tmpArr(i, 2)) = tmpDict(tmpArr(i, 2)) + 1
            End If
            ' Write nested Dictionary back to Main dictionary
            Set Dict(tmpArr(i, 1)) = tmpDict
        Next i

        ' Repurpose array for output setting to maximum possible size (helps with speed of code)
        ReDim tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2), LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1))
        ' Set starting counters for array
        i = LBound(tmpArr, 1)
        j = LBound(tmpArr, 2)
        ' Convert dictionary and nested dictionary to flat output
        For Each key In Dict
            tmpArr(j, i) = key
            i = i + 1
            For Each v In Dict(key)
                tmpArr(j, i) = v
                tmpArr(j + 1, i) = Dict(key)(v)
                i = i + 1
            Next v
        Next key
        ' Reshape array to actual size
        ReDim Preserve tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1), LBound(tmpArr, 2) To i - 1)
        ' Change this to the starting cell of your output
        With ws1.Cells(2, 5)

            Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Cells(UBound(tmpArr, 2), UBound(tmpArr, 1))) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This summarises the following data

```
Code    Tbk Mnth
C7  01-Apr-12
PP  01-Mar-18
PP  01-Jan-18
BK  01-Feb-17
FB  01-Feb-17
B9  01-Jan-17
B2  01-Mar-17
```

like this

```
A&  
2018/05/01  1
A1  
2016/08/01  1
2016/12/01  1
2018/01/01  1
2018/02/01  95
2018/03/01  418
2018/04/01  351
2018/05/01  41
2018/06/01  746
2018/07/01  2
A4  
2018/06/01  1
2018/07/01  1
AH  
2017/03/01  34
2017/12/01  3
2018/01/01  9
2018/02/01  43
2018/03/01  136
2018/04/01  1
2018/05/01  1
```

What do I change to transpose it and get it to look like this:-

```
        2016/08/01  2016/12/01  2018/01/01  2018/02/01  2018/03/01  2018/04/01  2018/05/01  2018/06/01  2018/07/01
A1      1   1   1   95  418 351 41  746 2
```

Comment: we are going to need a better explanation of the problem before we can suggest a solution.

Comment: I am not seeing a question here, am i missing something ?

Comment: even after editing this question is still a bit broad and your sample data does not even match. Providing an [mcve] of what you have tried to accomplish your task and where its not working will help us help you more.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman code summarises code going down 1 column at the moment. I would like to transpose the output and have the dates as headings in the columns and the number of times the date appears under the heading. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Anthony - that part is clear, what is not helpful to us is that you basically gave a code dump and are asking us to do *all the refactoring* for you without showing any effort of you trying anything on your own. Also, your initial dataset and your results are not consistent. For example, I do not see `A&`, `A1` etc. at all in your initial dataset.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for looking at my question. The data is inconsistent because I took a snapshot of data that is 28000 lines long. I do not expect you to do all the work for me. I would appreciate some tips as to where to start achieving what I want to do.

Comment: Can this not be done using a pivot off the original data?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes it can be done with a pivot table but I want to be able to write the code so that I may learn how to do it.

Comment: @Anthony i think it's a little bit more tricky than just transposing, you will need to get an array of all the unique dates and then each code and it's dates.  The unique dates will simply be for the header, then you'll need to use a combination of your transposing code and these headers, or will the dates be headers for each code, so differing dates each code

Comment: @Nathan_Sav The macro already creates unique dates for each code. I would be happy with different dates for each code.

Comment: @Tom wrote the macro in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two dictionaries of unique dates and codes (where the values are just incrementing numbers) - then use those dictionaries as you loop over your data, feed the numeric dictionary values onto Offset() to identify the correct cell in the grid and increment the value there

```
Sub Pivot()

    Dim rngData As Range, dDate, dCode, rw As Range, rOff As Long, cOff As Long
    Dim shtP As Worksheet

    Set shtP = Sheets("Pivot")

    With Sheets("Data")
        Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
    End With

    Set dDate = UniquesAndOrderFromRange(rngData.Columns(1))
    Set dCode = UniquesAndOrderFromRange(rngData.Columns(2))

    shtP.UsedRange.Clear
    shtP.Range("B3").Resize(dCode.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dCode.keys)
    shtP.Range("C2").Resize(1, dDate.Count).Value = dDate.keys


    For Each rw In rngData.Rows
        rOff = dCode(rw.Cells(2).Value)
        cOff = dDate(rw.Cells(1).Value)
        With shtP.Range("B2").Offset(rOff, cOff)
            Debug.Print rw.Cells(2).Value, rOff, rw.Cells(1).Value, cOff
            .Value = .Value + 1
        End With
    Next rw

End Sub


Property Get UniquesAndOrderFromRange(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, i As Integer, tmp, d
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    i = 0
    For Each c In rng.Cells
       tmp = c.Value
       If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
            If Not d.Exists(tmp) Then
                 i = i + 1
                 d.Add tmp, i
            End If
       End If
    Next c
    Set UniquesAndOrderFromRange = d
End Property
```